# Check if ethernet port has died

Tags: pi-2, ethernet

I was successfully using my rPi2B until I ran a full update of the software and firmware on the `Volumio 1.55` image.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo rpi-update
```

This caused some issues with the HAT I was using so I decided to wipe the SD card and reinstall the image. After reading some threads on forums it *may* be a kernel issue.

Now when I connect the pi, I see that the `pwr` (red) and `act` (green) leds are on constantly but the ethernet port has no lights at all.

I cannot SSH into the pi anymore (router does not detect the pi) and the hdmi port does not display anything. I have tried a different SD card and ethernet cables. My power supply is 5A 2V.

While I wait on a different image to dl, what other steps can I do to test if the ethernet port is working correctly?

Comment: Does SSH report an error?  The security credentials would have been newly created on the Pi and SSH will complain if it can talk to the Pi?

Comment: The Pi isn't even detected on the network anymore

Comment: I suspect the card has not been reimaged properly.  Do the LEDs flash when power is applied?

Comment: @joan actually no, they just turn on and stay lit. No flashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now when I connect the pi, I see that the pwr (red) and act (green) leds are on constantly but the ethernet port has no lights at all.

Steady green ACT on a model 2 is an unusable (e.g., not formatted correctly) or absent SD card.

Try taking the SD card out and turning it on.  You'll get the same thing as you are now.

Comment: That was it! Somehow I fluked formatting the SD the first time...